# how to alter some text with 2 arrays in fish script?

Tags: linux, fish

I'm a newbie in fish. I'm trying to alter a text in a file using sed. I want to perform 4 edits :

```
set ar1 old1 old2 old3 old4
set ar2 new1 new2 new3 new4
set i 1 #for 2nd array
for ch in $ar1
  sed -i 's/$c/$ar[$i]/g' file.php
  set i (math $i + 1)
end
```

But I found it doesn't increment itself.

Why doesn't it work? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes will prevent variable expansion. Use double quotes. https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#quotes

An alternate way to loop:

```
for i in (seq (count $ar1))
  sed -i "s/$ar1[$i]/$ar2[$i]/g" file.php
end
```